# Why does loc[[]] not work for a single column?

Tags: python, pandas, syntax-error

In the official documentation for the loc function in pandas, it is written that using double brackets, loc[[]], returns a dataframe.

> Single tuple. Note using [[]] returns a DataFrame.
> https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#

But this seems to not work when I am trying to convert a single column.

So for example, for a dataframe df

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]],
     index=['cobra', 'viper', 'sidewinder'],
     columns=['max_speed', 'shield'])
```

I get code results as follows

[image]

In the last case, it seems that using double brackets on a single column gives a syntax error. I do not understand this as using a single bracked worked for a single column, and using double brackets worked for a single row. Can someone explain to me why this happens?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use `:` for selecting all rows and `[]` for get one column to one column `DataFrame`:

```
print (df.loc[:, ['max_speed']])
            max_speed
cobra               1
viper               4
sidewinder          7
```

what is alternative:

```
print (df[['max_speed']])
            max_speed
cobra               1
viper               4
sidewinder          7
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you wrongly parsed what `.loc[['x']]` means. The double brackets are no special "dataframe operator" (`[[ 'x' ]]`). Rather, you are passing a list of one or more row names into single brackets (`[ ['x'] ]`). If you pass only one argument, it will be interpreted as row labels and the column labels are implicitly set to `:` (= all of them). If you wanna set column labels to something else, you need to add another parameter to `.loc[]`, **not** to `.loc[[]]`, i.e., `.loc[<row_labels>, <col_labels>]`, where the parameters can be either lists or strings.

As a rule of thumb, *the number of lists (including the shortcut `:`) you pass to `loc` gives you the number of dimensions of the output*:
Pass two lists, you get a dataframe (2D). (Note that if you only pass a single list and nothing else, it is implicitly `[your_list, :]` == two lists).
Pass one list, one string, you get a a series (1D). Pass two strings, you get a 0D object, or a scalar, i.e., the value in the cell.